# How to make this algorithm faster. Calculates and searches through large arrays

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, .net, sorting

I've got this algorithm that's "complex". The comments in code give examples of how large the various data types could be. My CPU usage is less than 10% when running this and RAM usage is good. No leakage or anything.

I have a list of arrays, where each array is x coordinates. We are storing a list of several x coordinate-groups essentially. = `xs` in code.
And I have the same thing but for y-values = `ys`.

Each array in `xs` and `ys` are different sizes. HOWEVER, the size of `xs` and `ys` is always the same. So if an array in xs contains 321654 elements then there is a corresponding array in ys with exactly 321654 elements.

The corresponding elements or "paired" `xs` and `ys` arrays are always at the same index in their corresponding list. So if xs_array[321654] is in `xs[4]` then ys_array[321654] is at `ys[4]`.

The following code aims to get mean values, standard deviation and -1std and +1std from mean, as y coordinates from a collection of coordinates. It does this by taking the smallest arrays (the smallest set of x and y coordinates. It then looks at each array in `xs` and finds the index at which the x-coordinates are in the array. It then goes into `ys`, finds the corresponding `xs` array, and gets the y value from the x-coordinate. It goes through this, adds it all up. calculate, mean, std etc etc.

```
    List<Double[]> xs;  //each array may be be e.g 40000 elements. and the list contains 50 - 100 of those
    List<Double[]> ys; //a list containing arrays with an exact equal size as xs

public void main_algorithm()
{
    
    int TheSmallestArray = GetSmallestArray(xs); //get the smallest array out of xs and store the size in TheSmallestArray
    for (int i = 0; i < TheSmallestArray; i++) 
    {
        double The_X_at_element = The_Smallest_X_in_xs[i]; //store the value at the index i
        //go through each array find the element at which x_values is at. If it doesnt exist, find the closest element. 
        List<Double> elements = new List<double>(); //create a new list of doubles
        for (int o = 0; o<xs.Count(); o++) //go through each array in xs
        {
            //go through the array o and find the index at which the number or closest number of the_X_at_element is
            int nearestIndex = Array.IndexOf(xs[o], xs[o].OrderBy(number => Math.Abs(number - The_X_at_element)).First()); 
            double The_Y_at_index = ys[o][nearestIndex]; //go through ys and get the value at this index
            elements.Add(The_Y_at_index); store the value in elements
        }
        mean_values.Add(elements.Mean()); //get the mean of all the values from ys taken
        standard_diviation_values.Add(elements.PopulationStandardDeviation());//get the mean of all the values from ys taken
        Std_MIN.Add(mean_values[i] - standard_diviation_values[i]); //store the mean - std and add to min
        Std_MAX.Add(mean_values[i] + standard_diviation_values[i]); //store the mean + std and add to max
    }
}

 public int GetSmallestArray(List<double[]> arrays)
{
    int TheSmallestArray = int.MaxValue;
    foreach(double[] ds in arrays)
    {
        if(ds.Length < TheSmallestArray)
        {
            TheSmallestArray = ds.Length; //store the length as TheSmallestArray
            The_Smallest_X_in_xs = ds;//and the entirety of the array ds as TheSmallestArray_xs
        }
    }
    return TheSmallestArray;
}
```

Comment: Can the arrays be sorted prior to calling this code? Being able to do a binary search to find `nearestIndex` would improve performance

Comment: There is a lot of context missing here: What significance is the shortest *xs* array? Does the order of elements in `mean_values`, Std_MIN`/`MAX` & `standard_diviation_values` (sic) matter (beyond values at the same index describing the same thing - quite redundantly), what are they used for?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not contain an explicit specification of what the code is to achieve.
The code presented for review suffers from that very problem - How can anyone tell what deviations are allowable?

- variable names are an odd mix of *PascalCase* and *snake_case*

Tactical:

- if `GetSmallestArray()` returned an array (the name suggests this), the length could be (re-) established without an enclosing-scope variable
- use an ordered clone `shortestX` of the smallest array(`xs`)
  and two arrays `noGreater` and `noSmaller` of same size
- for each array of x values
     initialise `noGreater` and `noSmaller` suitably
     find each value in `shortestX` (or the ones just below and/or above)
       and update `noGreater` and `noSmaller` accordingly
     for each value in `shortestX`, take the closer one from `noGreater`
       and `noSmaller`, find and use its index in the current array

Strategic:

`CPU usage is less than 10%` Guess: the computer showing this has many cores and uses few.
If above change in algorithm does not improve run time to *good enough*,

- look for further improvements in data presentation and processing
- only then give concurrency more than a side-glance